# Building qt3d for qt5.1.1 for android under windows

Tags: qt5

I am trying to compile qt3d for qt5 for android under windows. 
For this purpose, I followed those steps: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding

Instead of building QtCreator and Qt5 myself, I've just downloaded the android version for windows from this page: http://qt-project.org/downloads
This worked well for building common qt-projects for android, but compiling qt3d for android didn't work as intended.
I've downloaded qt3d from qit, via the download button on the right side(not a clone of that repository), opened that project, configured it to use my qt5-android and tried to download.

I get always such following compile errors:

```
C:\Qt\qt3d\qt-qt3d\src\threed\global\qglnamespace.h:45: Fehler:Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h: No such file or directory
```

It looks like, it tries to include header files, which are not present...at least not in the project folder structure. If I look in the include directory, those folders(QT3D, QTQuick3d) are present, but there are none of the necessary header files. So I believe the qmake process fails at some point.

While analyzing the .pro-files, the compilation process throws some other errors referring to cmake:

```
Project MESSAGE: cmake executable not found. Not running CMake unit tests
```

Whole compilation output:

```
14:31:52: Führe Schritte für Projekt qt3d aus...
14:31:52: Starte "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Qt\qt3d\qt-qt3d\qt3d.pro -r -spec android-g++
Info: creating cache file C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/.qmake.cache
Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/src.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/threed/threed.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/quick3d/quick3d.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/imports/imports.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/imports/threed/threed.pro
Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tools/tools.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tools/qt3d/qt3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tools/qt3d/qglinfo/qglinfo.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tools/meshcvt/meshcvt.pro
Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/examples.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/qt3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/basket/basket.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/builder/builder.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/cube/cube.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/cylinder/cylinder.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/geometry/geometry.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/nesting/nesting.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/solarsystem/solarsystem.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/tank/tank.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/teapot/teapot.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/qt3d/load_model/load_model.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/quick3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/basket/basket.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/cube/cube.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/forest/forest.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/lander/lander.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/matrix_animation/matrix_animation.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/positional_lighting/positional_lighting.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/monkeygod/monkeygod.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/moon/moon.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/photoroom/photoroom.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/shaders/shaders.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/sphere/sphere.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/examples/quick3d/animations/animations.pro
Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/demos.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/qt3d/qt3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/qt3d/teaservice/teaservice.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/qt3d/shapes/shapes.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/qt3d/pageflip/pageflip.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/qt3d/cubehouse/cubehouse.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/qt3d/photobrowser3d/photobrowser3d.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/quick3d/quick3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/quick3d/robo_bounce/robo_bounce.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/quick3d/tea_service/tea_service.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/demos/quick3d/flickr3d/flickr3d.pro
Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/tests.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/manual.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/animations/animations.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/basic/basic.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/background/background.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/displaymodel/displaymodel.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/fullreferencing/fullreferencing.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/model3ds/model3ds.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/navigation1/navigation1.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/qrc/qrc.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/rotation/rotation.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/scaling/scaling.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/shapes/shapes.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/submesh/submesh.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/translation/translation.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/manual/transformations/transformations.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/auto.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/threed.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qareaallocator/qareaallocator.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qarray/qarray.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qbox3d/qbox3d.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qcolor4ub/qcolor4ub.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qcustomdataarray/qcustomdataarray.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qgeometrydata/qgeometrydata.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglabstractsurface/qglabstractsurface.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglattributedescription/qglattributedescription.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglattributeset/qglattributeset.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglattributevalue/qglattributevalue.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglbezierpatches/qglbezierpatches.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglbuilder/qglbuilder.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglcamera/qglcamera.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglcameraanimation/qglcameraanimation.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglcube/qglcube.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglindexbuffer/qglindexbuffer.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qgllightmodel/qgllightmodel.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qgllightparameters/qgllightparameters.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglmaterial/qglmaterial.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglmaterialcollection/qglmaterialcollection.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglpainter/qglpainter.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglpickcolors/qglpickcolors.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglrender/qglrender.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglscenenode/qglscenenode.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglsection/qglsection.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglsphere/qglsphere.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglvertexbundle/qglvertexbundle.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qgraphicstransform3d/qgraphicstransform3d.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qplane3d/qplane3d.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qray3d/qray3d.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglcylinder/qglcylinder.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qsphere3d/qsphere3d.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qtriangle3d/qtriangle3d.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qvectorarray/qvectorarray.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/load_model/load_model.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/threed/qglcolladafxeffectfactory/qglcolladafxeffectfactory.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/cmake/cmake.pro
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/imports/imports.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/imports/qcapsulemesh/qcapsulemesh.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/imports/qcylindermesh/qcylindermesh.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/imports/qspheremesh/qspheremesh.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/imports/qline/qline.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/imports/qpoint/qpoint.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/qml3d/qml3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/qml3d_visual/qml3d_visual.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/qml3d_cpp/qml3d_cpp.pro
   Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/auto/qml3d_cpp/picking/picking.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/benchmarks/benchmarks.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/benchmarks/qarray/qarray.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/benchmarks/qglbuilder_perf/qglbuilder_perf.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tests/benchmarks/matrix_properties/matrix_properties.pro
Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/tutorials.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/qt3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/penguin/penguin.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/penguin_advanced/penguin_advanced.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/cube1/cube1.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/cube2/cube2.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/cube3/cube3.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/qt3d/cube4/cube4.pro
 Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/quick3d/quick3d.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/quick3d/shadertut/shadertut.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/quick3d/teapot_bounce_qml/teapot_bounce_qml.pro
  Reading C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/tutorials/quick3d/teapot_qml/teapot_qml.pro
Project MESSAGE: cmake executable not found. Not running CMake unit tests
14:33:08: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe" wurde normal beendet.
14:33:08: Starte "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe C:\Qt\qt3d\qt-qt3d\src\src.pro -spec android-g++ -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src'
cd threed\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe C:\Qt\qt3d\qt-qt3d\src\threed\threed.pro -spec android-g++ -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/threed'
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I. -I..\..\include -I..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/include/Qt3D/5.3.0 -IC:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/include/Qt3D/5.3.0/Qt3D -I..\private -Iglobal -Ipainting -Iarrays -Ieffects -Imaterials -Igeometry -Iviewing -Imath3d -Iscene -Iscene_ai -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\code -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\code\BoostWorkaround -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\include -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\include\Compiler -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\ConvertUTF -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\zlib -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\irrXML -I..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\unzip -Iscene_bezier -Inetwork -Igraphicsview -Itextures -Isurfaces -Iapi -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui\5.1.1 -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui\5.1.1\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore\5.1.1 -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore\5.1.1\QtCore -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -o .obj\release_shared\qglnamespace.obj global\qglnamespace.cpp
In file included from global\qglnamespace.cpp:42:0:
global\qglnamespace.h:45:29: fatal error: Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8497: recipe for target '.obj\release_shared\qglnamespace.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [.obj\release_shared\qglnamespace.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src/threed'
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'sub-threed-make_first-ordered' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-threed-make_first-ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/qt3d/qt-qt3d/src'
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
makefile:43: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
14:33:12: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts qt3d(Kit: Android für arm (GCC 4.7, Qt 5.1.1)-Qt 5.1.1 for Android armv7)
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt 'Make'
```

Some other collegue of mine, said I should clone the whole repository, because the download is faulty. In my opinion, the qmake process is not working properly.

qmake:

```
qmake.exe C:\Qt\qt3d\qt-qt3d\qt3d.pro -r -spec android-g++
```

Make:

```
mingw32-make.exe in C:\Qt\qt3d\qt-qt3d
```

Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix that problem. The problem is the regular download of qt-3d from gitorious. It is necessary to clone that qt-3d git completely. That simple download produces errors, because header files were not copied to the include folders. Once the repository was cloned and compiled, qt-3d libs were created. Still those libraries were not copied to my qt5 installation. I had to do it manually(copy lib, inc, mkspecs to your qt5 installation). Only after that qt3d-module was recognized and somewhat usable.

Now I wanted to try to run an example project.

```
14:24:48: Running steps for project teapot...
14:24:48: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:24:48: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I. -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include -o .obj\release_shared\teapotview.obj teapotview.cpp
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I. -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include -o .obj\release_shared\main.obj main.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\bin\moc.exe -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I. -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include teapotview.h -o .moc\release_shared\moc_teapotview.cpp
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I. -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include -o .obj\release_shared\moc_teapotview.obj .moc\release_shared\moc_teapotview.cpp
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=C:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libteapot.so -Wl,-rpath-link=C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/android_armv7/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o ..\..\..\bin\libteapot.so .obj\release_shared\teapotview.obj .obj\release_shared\main.obj .obj\release_shared\moc_teapotview.obj   -LC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi-v7a -LC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:/Qt/qt-3d/lib -lQt53D -lgnustl_shared -lsupc++ -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\lib -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 
14:24:56: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:24:56: Elapsed time: 00:08.
```

So compilation of the teapot example looked good. But deployment fails...

```
14:27:22: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:27:22: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="C:\Qt\qt-3d\examples\qt3d\teapot\android" install
Die Syntax fr den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentr„gerbezeichnung ist falsch.
makefile:1686: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 1
14:27:24: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project teapot (kit: Android für arm (GCC 4.7, Qt 5.1.1)-Qt 5.1.1 for Android armv7)
When executing step 'Anwendungsdaten kopieren'
14:27:24: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Normaly after deployment a apk file should be created, but nothing like that happens. For that teapot example a .obj folder with some obj-files is created, but creating executable fails.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to compile qt3d 1.x for Qt 4.8.4 for BB10. The missing headers were some private headers that aren't available in the pre-built Qt SDK from BB NDK, however they are available if you download the Qt source and compile it on your own. Instead of compiling Qt 4.8.4 for BB10, I googled the header file names for Qt 4.8.4 and copied them in the corresponding location of my existing Qt installation. Hope that helps.